# C application linking failing with "undefined reference to __mulhi3"

Tags: c, static-linking, undefined-reference, avr-gcc, missing-symbols

I designed a static library for use in my AVR projects, but I'm having trouble linking it to an application. It reports this error:

```
libteleobjects/libteleobjects.a(telesignals.c.obj): In function `telesignal_get_event_data':                                                               
/home/claudio/git/ucp-usc64/libteleobjects/telesignals.c:559: undefined reference to `__mulhi3'
/home/claudio/git/ucp-usc64/libteleobjects/telesignals.c:561: undefined reference to `__mulhi3'
/home/claudio/git/ucp-usc64/libteleobjects/telesignals.c:561: undefined reference to `__mulhi3'
/home/claudio/git/ucp-usc64/libteleobjects/telesignals.c:561: undefined reference to `__mulhi3'
```

I found an interesting investigation to the same problem [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.hardware.avr.ada/622), but since his solution is all about ADA I have no idea how to fix it in my case, which is a `C` application. It gave me nice tips though, like using `avr-nm` to search for this symbol in the system libraries. Unlike in his case, here the symbol `__mulhi3` displays as `U` (undefined) even in the avr system libs where it was supposed to be found (`libgcc.a` for his libs from AVR-GCC 4.7.2 - mine is 4.8.0), so I guess the `__mulhi3` is not defined at all(!?). I would expect it should appear as `T` (defined in the `text` section) in the system libs (`.a` files in /usr/avr/lib and subdirs). Any tips? As a sidenote, I'm using CMake as the build system.

**EDIT:**

Like suggested [here](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=printview&t=76720&start=0) and in the answer below, adding the math library to the end of linking would supposedly solve the problem, but CMake is already doing it and it didn't work yet:

```
Linking C executable ucp-usc64.elf
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/ucp-usc64.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/avr-gcc  -g -Os       -mcall-prologues -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Os -DNDEBUG -w -mcall-prologues -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -Wl,--gc-sections -lm -Wl,--gc-sections -lm -mmcu=atmega644p  CMakeFiles/ucp-usc64.dir/main.c.obj CMakeFiles/ucp-usc64.dir/modutr_callbacks.c.obj  -o ucp-usc64.elf  -lc -lm avr-drivers/libavr_drivers.a modutr-slave/lib/libmodutr_slave.a libteleobjects/libteleobjects.a -lc -lm 
libteleobjects/libteleobjects.a(telesignals.c.obj): In function `telesignal_get_event_data':
/home/claudio/git/ucp-usc64/libteleobjects/telesignals.c:559: undefined reference to `__mulhi3'
/home/claudio/git/ucp-usc64/libteleobjects/telesignals.c:561: undefined reference to `__mulhi3'
/home/claudio/git/ucp-usc64/libteleobjects/telesignals.c:561: undefined reference to `__mulhi3'
/home/claudio/git/ucp-usc64/libteleobjects/telesignals.c:561: undefined reference to `__mulhi3'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: can I see your build script?

Comment: 2nded. Post you CMakesists.txt plz

Comment: @ExcelledProducts, since I'm using CMake, it makes up the linking "under the hood", so I guess this would be the build script for the linking part (`link.txt` file):
`/usr/bin/avr-gcc  -g -Os       -mcall-prologues -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Os -DNDEBUG -w -mcall-prologues -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -Wl,--gc-sections -lm -Wl,--gc-sections -lm -mmcu=atmega644p  CMakeFiles/ucp-usc64.dir/main.c.obj CMakeFiles/ucp-usc64.dir/modutr_callbacks.c.obj  -o ucp-usc64.elf  -lc -lm avr-drivers/libavr_drivers.a libteleobjects/libteleobjects.a modutr-slave/lib/libmodutr_slave.a -lc -lm`

Comment: You may want to try with a g++ or gcc compiler with the -l linking all the libraries. That is what your error means. That you are not linking a library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol `__mulhi3` is indeed defined by `libgcc.a`, like previously hinted by [this link](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.hardware.avr.ada/622). The problem was that, when CMake's variable CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE was set to **Release**, the following flags are used (set through CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE):

`-Os -DNDEBUG -mcall-prologues -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-exceptions`

and it appears the use of optimization `-Os` causes the internal GCC function `__mulhi3` to be used. In that situation, somehow CMake wasn't looking for `libgcc.a` in the place where it is in my system, which is `/usr/lib/avr/gcc/4.8.0/libgcc.a`.

I already knew beforehand `undefined reference` errors always happen when a library or object file defining a symbol is not linked in, and everybody helping me here were pointing in the right direction too, but I was really misled by the fact I was looking for `libgcc.a` in the wrong place like this:

```
cd /usr/avr/lib
find -name "*.a" -exec avr-nm {} \; | grep "__mulhi3"
```

That was just returning loads of `__mulhi3` marked as `U`, which meant it should be defined somewhere else. Just after checking up my package contents for avr-gcc I found `libgcc.a` was placed at `/usr/lib/gcc/avr/4.8.0`.

Turns out in the end the whole problem was more related to CMake not being pointed the right place to look for `libgcc.a`, which I got to work by adding the line:

`set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-L /usr/lib/gcc/avr/4.8.0")`

to `CMakeLists.txt`, which causes the following and successful linker invocation:

```
/usr/bin/avr-gcc  -Wall -Os -DNDEBUG -w -mcall-prologues -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -L /usr/lib/gcc/avr/4.8.0 -Wl,--gc-sections -lm -mmcu=atmega644p  CMakeFiles/ucp-usc64.dir/main.c.obj CMakeFiles/ucp-usc64.dir/modutr_callbacks.c.obj  -o ucp-usc64.elf  -lc -lm avr-drivers/libavr_drivers.a libteleobjects/libteleobjects.a modutr-slave/lib/libmodutr_slave.a -lc -lm
```

Answer (score 1):

What does your CMake target_link_libraries argument look like?

My guess is you need to add  "m" (lower case m) to pull in the math library.

Comment: Does the line above hint anything to you Joshua? I see the `-lm` in many places, although I really didn't specify it in LDFLAGS or anything like that (I guess CMake included it by itself).

Comment: My `target_link_libraries` looks like this:
`target_link_libraries(ucp-usc64 avr_drivers teleobjects_static lib_modutr_slave_static)`. I'll append the `-lm` in the end to check it out, but I guess CMake already did it, like shown above - `teleobjects_static` is CMake's target name for `libteleobjects.a` lib.

Comment: @Claudio I edited my reply, I remembered after I posted that Cmake wants just "m" in the target_link_libraries for "-lm"

Comment: Joshua, if I add either `-lm` or `m` the result is the same, it just adds another `-lm` by the end of the linker line (it even ends up duplicated, because CMake already put the first one), but it still doesn't work.

Comment: The ada related link seemed to think the missing define was in libgcc.a, perhaps you should try adding "gcc" or "static-libgcc.a"?

Comment: Unfortunately adding `-lgcc` doesn't work either. And it is really funny that symbol `__mulhi3` shows as `U` (undefined?) by `avr-nm` in any of the gcc static libs (those found at /usr/avr/lib and its subdirs).

Comment: Maybe your library paths have something getting the wrong library version for your MCU, or generic libraries taking precedence? Seehttp://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=printview&t=76720&start=0

Comment: Joshua, I found I was misled by not finding the symbol in /usr/avr/lib, in my system the symbol `__mulhi3` is really defined in /usr/lib/gcc/avr/4.8.0/libgcc.a, I just didn't post the solution yet because I'm very busy right now.. but thanks for the help and suggestions anyway!